# what is the sequence of jquery pageload events?

Tags: jquery

are there any good guides as to which events happen in which order (and what triggers them)?

ie:

```
$(document).ready
$(window).ready
$(window).onload
```

---

EDIT: are there any other (pageload) events that i'm missing?

Comment: For your edit...none that would matter 99% of the time, what are you actually after here?  Knowing the end-game may lead to a better answer.

Comment: just general curiousity!

Comment: There's no `$(window).onload`. There's `window.onload` and `$(window).load()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `document.ready` - DOM Elements good to go

   - Triggered by `DOMContentLoaded` in Mozilla/WebKit/Opera
   - Trigered by `onreadystatechange` in IE
2. `window.load` - Images loaded

   - The actual `window.onload` event, this is a core DOM event, not created by jQuery.

`document.ready` happens before or when `window.load` does...if all else fails, `document.ready` is actually an event handler on `window.load`, you can see the source code here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L407

There isn't a `window.ready`, `document.ready` is a special event that jQuery creates, only for `document` and not `window`.

Comment: Actually the jQuery event "ready" isn't even bound to the document. See the jQuery 3.0 notes in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/): "the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method".

Answer (score 4):

- **$(document).ready** when the browser is done rendering the DOM (the HTML file)
- **$(window).ready** never heard of that one. Don't think it exists
- **$(window).onload** when every linked resource on the page (including images) was loaded (usually some time after `document.ready`)

Comment: jQuery ignores the element in its `ready()` method, so `$(anything).ready()` is equivalent to `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 3):

1. $(document).ready
2. $(window).onload (document + multimedia (like images))

There isn't $(window).ready

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know

1. $(document).ready
2. $(window).onload

Answer (score 0):

All answers are right, but just to clarify.

It's `window.onload` or `$(window).load`

There's no `$(window).onload` nor `window.load`