# Alert message after submitting form in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using form with POST method to apply session, once the form is submitted the page reloads and I can't have any alerts on the screen.

So I've used some trick I found online but it has a problem, the alert pops up after the form submitted but none of the page design works, meaning I have only blank page and alert message.

After I click "OK' to close the alert message, the page loads.

```
if(empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $cartArray;
    $status = "Product is added to your cart!";
    header('location:product.php?status=success');
}else{
    $array_keys = array_keys($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
    if(in_array($code,$array_keys)) {
        $status = "Product is already added to your cart!";
        header('location:product.php?status=failed');
    } else {
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = array_merge($_SESSION["shopping_cart"],$cartArray);
        $status = "Product is added to your cart!";
        header('location:product.php?status=success');
    }

}

// This right here responsible to alert the message according to the status.
if( $_GET['status'] == 'success') {
   echo '<script>  alert("welldone");   </script>';
}
else{
   echo '<script>  alert("no good");   </script>';
}
```

How can I solve the page loading order so the page loads first and the alert loads second?

[image]

Comment: Not the answer you are looking for. But ... JavaScript :)

Comment: Are these two different scripts? If `// This right here responsible to alert the message according to the status.` is on `product.php` that should be correct.

Comment: Move the "offending" code to the bottom of the page. If it appears before all of the HTML on the page, it will act first... So the pop up appears before the page is rendered and waits for the user to click it closed.

Comment: @user3783243 they are both on the same page.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak The alert is on the bottom of the page, near the ending of body tag.

Comment: Right before the </body> tag? Can you post the browser source code of the page, or provide a link?

Comment: @JeffVdovjak https://codeshare.io/5e1xmA  Here is my source code.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery you could use $(document).ready()

Comment: @JeffVdovjak Now the alert doesn't show at all.

Comment: Like this? `$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert('message');
});`  I believe the popup script would have to be moved to the head for that as well.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak It works but still failing to load the page before the alert.

Comment: try the `$(window).load()` event. Maybe look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910637/what-jquery-event-is-called-right-after-document-ready or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185351/what-is-the-sequence-of-jquery-pageload-events

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What jQuery event is called right after $(document).ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910637/what-jquery-event-is-called-right-after-document-ready)

Comment: I found a workaround solution. Everything I tried with document ready, or on window load wouldn't work (including above). But I think I have it. I'll post it as an answer because so many people have this problem -- and it needs more than a comment.

Comment: Do NOT use `alert()` it's blocking everything.

Comment: The op asked how he could use alert() so this comment isn't helpful. Also, what is it "blocking"? It's occuring before he would like it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long researching, I found solution to delay the alert message with jQuery `delay()` function, the delay allowing the HTML page load and then execute the alert.
Thanks to all who helped me to get to this result.

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          setTimeout(function() {
              <?php
              if( $_GET['status'] == 'success') {
                  echo 'alert("welldone");';
              }
              else{
                  echo 'alert("no good");';
              }
              ?>
              }, 500);
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: why using alert on javascript. put a <div><?php if ($error) { echo "problem."}?></div>. It's simple, efficient, clear, not blocking, maintenable, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble with this one -- even using old answers marked "correct".

I found a work around. On window load and document ready didn't work. But if you add an image at the bottom of the page with the following script, it won't get called until the image is loaded (at the end of the page load).

This worked in all my testing.

```
<img id='workaround' src='https://picsum.photos/1/1'> <!-- any transparent 1x1 image would work -->
<script>
$("#workaround").on( "load", function(){
  alert("Image loaded.");
});
</script>
```

So for your purposes (or similar)

```
<img id='workaround' src='https://picsum.photos/1/1'>
<script>
$("#workaround").on( "load", function(){

<?php 
if( $_GET['status'] == 'success') {
   echo 'alert("welldone");';
}
else{
   echo 'alert("no good");';
}
?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the right usage? once I apply .load() function the console tells me there is an error using it.

Comment: You're probably using a newer jQuery than I used. Use the `.on( "load", handler )` instead. I'll update. (.load() was changed in jQuery 3+)

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` stops the execution of the script and the loading of the HTML page at the point in which it was called. You should move this script to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Looked at the code in the link, it seems alright, the only odd thing is: why are you using `sleep` with PHP? 
Also have you checked the browser's console to see if there are any JavaScript errors?

Comment: I was researching online for answers, thought that might be good idea. [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 1773ms This is the console, but thats odd because I haven't used timeout handler. maybe its part of the alert.

Comment: Even if you do a strictly HTML page with alert() at the bottom of the page, it occurs before the page is rendered. That's the problem we keep having.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To alert message after submitting form in PHP.

```
<?
if ($_POST)
    {
    if (empty($_POST['testabc'])) $msg='<script type="text/javascript">alert("BLANK");</script>';
    else $msg='<script type="text/javascript">alert("NOT BLANK");</script>';
    }
?>
<html><head></head><body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form id="finfo" method=POST>
                <input type="text" name="testabc">
                <input type="submit" value="info">
            </form> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">alert("auto");</script>
<? echo $msg; ?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, tried even to apply it on blank page, same result. also one extra alert is popping up

Answer (score 0):

You could defer the script tag and it won't load until after the page is rendered.

```
<script src="alert.js" defer></script>
```

Then it will load after the page renders, and there won't be a random delay (like using wait/jquery delay).

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap modal could also be a better option. Modal looks prettier than alert dialogue box. It does not change current page layout during message display.

In php code:

```
// This right here responsible to alert the message according to the status.
$message = '';
$show_modal = false;
if( $_GET['status'] == 'success') {
    $message = "Well Done";
    $show_modal = true;
}
else{
    $message = "No Good";
    $show_modal = true;
}
```

In html head tag:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then in the html:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Alert!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><?php echo ($message); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Finally show modal with condition in js:

```
<?php if($show_modal):?>
    <script> $('#myModal').modal('show');</script>
<?php endif;?>
```